# Background image will not appear on website

Tags: html, css, web, background-image

I have a mainContainer on my site that I want to add a background image to. When I try to add the image I use this css

```
#mainContainer {
  background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The image is a safe size. I think 1000x1000 or something around there. When I try to refresh the page I get a strange error:

[image]

I am using bootstrap4. Does the error on top have anything to do with my image not displaying or is it something in the css?

Also this is how my file structure looks if it helps:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding Tether?

Comment: can you give the link of your site?

Comment: Try enclosing the url in quotes `background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");`

Comment: File paths in CSS are relative to the CSS file, not HTML. Also the Console error clearly states that it tried to load `assets/css/images/bg.jpg` but that directory does not exist. To link to a file that is in another directory, use "`../`" to *go up* one folder, then choose the directory (images) and file (bg.jpg), resulting in `../images/bg.jpg`. Alternatively, you could move the `images` folder inside the `css` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The image file is not in the folder. You probably want to change it to `../images/bg.jpg` to if it is in `assets/images/` folder instead of `assets/css/images/`.

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I know this is kind of a generic question but the errors in the console had me questioning it. I will accept as soon as stackoverflow lets me

Answer (score 3):

Put this.

```
#mainContainer {
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try to add `background-position:center center`

Comment: and also add `background-repeat: no-repeat`